# Forcing geometry columns to be small on pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgis, pgadmin-4, geometry-data-type

On pgAdmin 4, geometry columns always show as huge lines:

[image]

So when I want to check the geometries inside Postgres I have to go all the way until the end of the line with a very small scroll bar:

[image]

That bothers me a little... Is there any way of forcing all columns or specific columns in a way that they won't show all the data that it has in each line when we use pgAdmin 4? I'd like to make it to be something as follows:

[image]

Comment: This has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68393713/avoid-columns-being-displayed-with-their-maximum-width-in-the-data-output-tab-in

Comment: I couldnt vote to close as "duplicate", it is not possible for a duplicate to be on another site than gis.stackexchange.com. I agree it is on topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the top left menu, go to "Files > Preferences" and then click the "Results grid" in the left column.

Change the "Maximum column width" to the desired value, here 200 pixels:

[image: Screenshot from pgadmin4 version 6.8.]
*Screenshot from pgadmin4 version 6.8.*

Click the "Save" button.

Execute your query again to see the changes.